# Stop decrementing to negative values when the value of a variable becomes zero

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This below code has Two values increment and decrement which are hooked to buttons in XML

```
int quantity = 0;;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trial_order);
}

public void increment(View view){
   quantity = quantity + 1;
    display(quantity);
}
public void decrement(View view){
    quantity = quantity - 1;
    display(quantity);
}
```

and increment works fine,decrement works fine too but when I press decrement it goes in 0,-1,-2,-3 and so on but I want 0 to be the final value when I use decrement button kindly help

Comment: Hint: use if condition.

Comment: 'if (quantity != 0){display(quantity);} else if (quantity == 0){break;} ' I tried this but didnt work,I am new to java dev

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check after decreasing if the value of **quantity** is getting lower than 0 and set it accordingly:

## Example:

```
public void decrement(View view){
    quantity--;
    if(quantity<0){
         quantity=0;  
    }
    display(quantity);
}
```

Comment: This can be further simplified by checking `if (quantity >= 1) { quantity --; }` instead of changing the value of `quantity` twice if is goes less than 0.

Comment: @OJ7 it should be `if (quantity >= 1) { quantity --; }`

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam fixed it :)

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
public void decrement(View view){
    quantity = quantity>0 ? --quantity : 0;
    display(quantity);
}
```

The above code decrements only if the value of `quantity` is greater than zero. otherwise it will just return zero.

Comment: strange... i wonder why. It is pretty much the same logic as the answer that worked for you. just using a conditional operator for smaller code.

Comment: did you actually try it as i wrote?

Comment: I was looking for a one-liner solution; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void decrement(View view)
{
  if(quantity==0)
  {
    display(quantity);
  }
  else
  {
    quantity--;
    display(quantity);
  }
}
```

My code doesn't allow the quantity to go below 0(Hope you understand)

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. And: what do you think is different from the  code in the existing answers?

Comment: I thin it is easier to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

/**
     * This method is called when the minus button is clicked.
     */
    public void decrement(View view) {
        if(quantity<2) quantity=1;
            quantity = quantity-1;
        display(quantity);
    }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain more why and how you answer works. Thanks :)